# $.post().html().show not 'showing' a <div>

Tags: jquery, html, show, .post

G'Day All,

I am trying to use the jQuery $.post function to pass some parameters to a PHP file which:

- Gathers flight booking info from a MySQL database,
- generates a HTML form with the data for display,
- return the HTML output into a hidden `<div>`,
- unhide the `<div>` so that it is over the top of the rest of the content of the page as a type of dialogue box.

The issue is, if I have the `<div id="bookingpop" style="display:none; ... ">`, the .show() in the jquery line that works to insert and display the output of the php file does not show (unhide) the `<div>`. (??)

As a test:

- if I take out the 'display:none;' style to always show the div (as is the state of the HTML code below), the output populates the element from the PHP via $.post works OK, but it is obviously always there (undesired).
- $("#bookingpop").hide() doesn't hide it if it is visible (again, as a test),
- The other things I've comented below the offending line (`alert(bid);` and `alert(output);`) both behave and display as expected if allowed to run.
- The date picker also works OK.
- having or not having the HTML remark between the open and closing tags of the #bookingpop `<div>` make no difference to the issue,
- IE8-9, FF10, Chrome, Safari on iPad 3, no difference other than IE interpreting the form field widths wider than the others.

The JS/jQuery in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passbooking(bid) { // <- bid is the Booking ID
        $.post("bookdisplay.php", { bookref: bid },
            function(output) {
                $("#bookingpop").html(output).show();
                // alert(bid);
                // alert(output);
            });
    };

    /* Code for th jQuery-ui date picker. */
    $(function() {
        // $("#bookingpop").hide();
        $( "#pick_DATE" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-m-d"
        });
    });

</script>
```

The HTML/PHP:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 124px; width: 157px; border: none; margin: 0;"><img alt="Logo" src="/act/images/avncol-logo.png" />
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left: 157px; top:0px; width: 1000px; height: 64px; border: none;">
  <h2>Aviation College Townsville:  Daily Run Sheet</h2>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 65px; left: 157px; height: 64px; width: 1000px;"><input type="text" id="pick_DATE" size="20" value="<?php echo $date ?>"/></div>

<?php
$booking_overlays = prepevents($date);
// var_dump($booking_overlays);
?>

<div class="parentDiv" style="top: 126px; left: 0px;">   <!-- create a parent div section to contain and reference the timeline <div> elements to -->
<?php
print $timesheet; // Prints a grid/daily planner made from <div> elements
print $booking_overlays; // Prints a event/bookings as time blocks over the planner (as <div>)
?>
</div>  <!-- Close the "parentDiv" -->

<!-- This div is the one that  pops up over the others to display the booking -->
<div id="bookingpop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color:#FFF; left: 200px; top: 50px; width: 610px; height: 500px; border: 3px solid; margin: 0;"><!-- the data goes in here --></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to JS/jQuery and am re-learning HTML (having not touched it since before CSS existed and JS was commonplace).
If anyone can see anything out of place (or simply wrong), please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The output of jQuery's html() method is a string -- not the associated jQuery element. So, you're calling show() on a string. Try this:

```
$("#bookingpop").show().html(output);
```

You could also do two separate lines:

```
$("#bookingpop").html(output);
$("#bookingpop").show();
```

Comment: `.html()` returns string, `.html(htmlString)` returns jQuery - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: I had tried the latter before with no luck, and reversing the show() andhtml did not have any effect either.  "output" is a text sring return with the HTML of the from and data, as verified by the  remarked `alert(output);` statement and by simply loading it up in the browser window with a defined parameter for "bid".

Comment: BTW, I got the code snippet from phpacademy's youtube on the subject [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8HoVdenZFM) at about the 12th minute (and have subsequently seen it elsewhere). It has worked in the past, and I have backtracked many of the things I've done, but none have made it work again.